# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'ICart'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to build a route with node and typescript where I can add products to a cart, however it is complaining about the interface.

Here is the interface in **interfaces.ts**:

```
import { Document } from "mongoose";
export interface IUser extends Document {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  cart: ICart;
  orders: IOrders[];
}

export interface ICart {
  total: number;
  count: number;
}
```

My model in **UserModel.ts**:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function (str: string) {
        return /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/g.test(str);
      },
      message: (props: { value: string }) =>
        `${props.value} is not a valid email`,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  cart: {
    type: Object,
    default: {
      total: 0,
      count: 0,
    },
  },
  orders: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Order" }],
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model<IUser>("User", UserSchema);

export default UserModel;
```

And lastly, the route in **productRoutes.ts**:

```
productRoutes.post('/add-to-cart', async(req, res)=> {
    const {userId, productId, price} = req.body;
    try {
      const user = await UserModel.findById(userId);
      const userCart = user.cart;
      if(user.cart[productId]){
        userCart[productId] += 1;
      } else {
        userCart[productId] = 1;
      }
      userCart.count += 1;
      userCart.total = Number(userCart.total) + Number(price);
      if (user) {
        user.cart = userCart;
        user.markModified('cart');
        await user.save();
      }
      res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).send(e);
    }
  })
```

The error I am getting is in productRoutes.ts, in my try catch, specifically in these two parts:

```
const userCart = user.cart; // Object is possibly 'null'
```

```
      if(user.cart[productId]){ // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'ICart'.
        userCart[productId] += 1; // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'ICart'.
      } else {
        userCart[productId] = 1; // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'ICart'.
      }
```

What am I doing wrong, where do I type it and how do I index type "ICart"?

Comment: const user: ICart = await UserModel.findById(userId);
Try if this works

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```js
const userCart = user.cart!;
```

Comment: When I do, I get the same error, that it is possibly null.

Comment: Sorry, `!` should be after the expression. I updated my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks, it solved the "Object is possibly 'null'". Do you have any idea what to do about the other errors?

Comment: You can check this: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-element-implicitly-has-any-type-expression#:~:text=The%20error%20%22Element%20implicitly%20has,one%20of%20the%20object's%20keys.

Answer (score 0):

#### First error

> const userCart = user.cart; // Object is possibly 'null'

TypeScript (rightfully) warns you that the `user` object can be null (which would happen if the document is not found in the user collection).

Instead of muting the error with the non-null assertion operator `!`, I suggest you make sure the document exists indeed:

```
  const { userId, productId, price } = req.body;

  const user = await UserModel.findById(userId);
  if (!user) {
    res.status(400).send("User not found");

    return;
  }

  const userCart = user.cart; // no TS errors
```

#### Second error

> if(user.cart[productId]){ // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'ICart'.

First, you want to properly type the request body, to let the compiler know the data type of `productId`.

```
interface IAddToCartRequestBody {
  userId: string;
  productId: string;
  price: number;
}

productRoutes.post('/add-to-cart', async (req: express.Request<any, any, IAddToCartRequestBody>, res) => {
  const { userId, productId, price } = req.body;

  ...
```

Second, allow product IDs as keys

```
export interface ICart {
  [productId: string]: number;
  total: number;
  count: number;
}
```

These updates combined should resolve all of the TypeScript errors (in strict mode).